# Referencing index for vectorization in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vector, vectorization

I have a couple of for loops that I want to vectorize in order to improve performance. They operate on 1 x N matrices.

```
for y in range(1, len(array[0]) + 1):
        array[0, y - 1] =  np.floor(np.nanmean(otherArray[0, ((y-1)*3):((y-1)*3+3)]))
```

```
for i in range(len(array[0])):
        array[0, int((i-1)*L+1)] = otherArray[0, i]
```

The operations are reliant on the index of the array which is given by the for loop. Is there any way to access the index while using numpy.vectorize so that I can rewrite these as vectorized functions?

Comment: In the 2nd the iterate `i` might be replaced with `I = np.arange(len(array[0]))` and some calculation using it.  But for the slicing in the first loop, there isn't a way ro replace the iterated `y` with an array.  In an `a:b` slice, `a` and `b` have to scalars.

Comment: Just FYI: Python range(n) starts at 0 and ends at n-1. So does numpy array indexing. Save yourself the trouble with the +1.

Answer (score 1):

First loop:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros((1, 10))
otherArray = np.arange(30).reshape(1, -1)


print(f'array = \n{array}')
print(f'otherArray = \n{otherArray}')

for y in range(1, len(array[0]) + 1):
        array[0, y - 1] =  np.floor(np.nanmean(otherArray[0, ((y-1)*3):((y-1)*3+3)]))

print(f'array = \n{array}')

array = np.floor(np.nanmean(otherArray.reshape(-1, 3), axis = 1)).reshape(1, -1)

print(f'array = \n{array}')
```

output:

```
array = 
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
otherArray = 
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
  24 25 26 27 28 29]]
array = 
[[ 1.  4.  7. 10. 13. 16. 19. 22. 25. 28.]]
array = 
[[ 1.  4.  7. 10. 13. 16. 19. 22. 25. 28.]]
```

Second loop:

```
array = np.zeros((1, 10))
otherArray = np.arange(10, dtype = float).reshape(1, -1)
L = 1

print(f'array = \n{array}')
print(f'otherArray = \n{otherArray}')


for i in range(len(otherArray[0])):
        array[0, int((i-1)*L+1)] = otherArray[0, i]

print(f'array = \n{array}')


array = otherArray

print(f'array = \n{array}')
```

output:

```
array = 
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
otherArray = 
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]]
array = 
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]]
array = 
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the first loop you are trying to compute a moving average. This is best done like this:

```
import numpy as np


window_width = 3
arr = np.arange(12)

out = np.floor(np.nanmean(arr.reshape(-1,window_width) ,axis=-1))

print(out)
```

Regarding your second loop, I have no clue what it does. You are trying to copy values from otherArray to array with some offset? I’d recommend you look at numpy’s slicing functionality.